# Pop function not working in stack

Tags: c, data-structures, stack

I am trying to execute the pop function but my pop function is not working.

I run pop and then show and it is printing only 0

```
typedef struct Stack
{
  int top;
  int elements[20];
}
stack;
stack s;
void pop()
{
  s.top--;
}


 void show() 
 { 
    while(s.top>=0)
    { 
      printf("%d\n",s.elements[s.top]); 
      s.top--; 
    }
 }
```

Comment: this pop function does not print anything so what do you mean printing zero?

Comment: I mean on executing show function after it  code                                         void show()
                                                 {
                                                       while(s.top>=0)
                                                          {
                                                         printf("%d\n",s.elements[s.top]);
                                                          s.top--;
                                                          }
                                                           }

Comment: Likely should be `while(s.top > 0) { printf("%d\n",s.elements[--s.top]); }`

Comment: It seems strange that your show function changes the value of top... shouldn't only pop change the value of top with this data type?

Comment: but then how to print it Hogan

Comment: @LEONARDO - print it in the calling function (eg `printf("%d\n",s.show());`)

Comment: Can you add your main function? It is not clear what behaviour you expect this code to produce.

Answer (score 1):

The function

```
void pop()
```

has a void return type. So it is not returning an object for you to print.

Comment: But I want to print the rest of the element not the element popped

Answer (score 0):

`pop` function should be

```
int pop()
{
    if(s.top == -1)  // -1 is delimiter for stack to be empty 
    {
         printf("Stack is empty\n");
         return -1;
    }
    return s.elements[s.top--];
}
```

Comment: since when does a pop function require you print the poped element?

Comment: Minor: `int pop(void)`

Comment: I guess, every stack type I've seen pop returns the value not prints it.

Comment: why should it return the popped element

Comment: @haccks not universal, I'd say there are two ADT -- in one pop returns the value after poping it.  in the other there is another function (named show or peek) that looks at the top value and pop just removes the top value unconditionally.